# Vue Router, When I refresh the page, it takes me to the homepage

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I put a login query on my page and keep membership information with local storage. When I refresh the page, I am constantly redirected to the homepage. Why am I experiencing this?

Thank you for your help.

```
{
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: () => import('./views/Home.vue'),
    beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
        if (store.getters.isAuth) {
            next();
        } else {
            next("/pages/login");
        }
    }
}, {
    path: '/blogs',
    name: 'blogs',
    component: () => import('./views/Blogs.vue'),
    beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
        if (store.getters.isAuth) {
            if (store.state.userData[0].user_role == 1 || store.state.userData[0].user_role == 2 || store.state.userData[0].user_role == 3) {
                next();
            } else {
                alert('you are not authorized');
            }
        } else {
            next("/pages/login")
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: check this variable value store.getters.isAuth  when it is coming again to router it does not have value put a debugger and verify value

Comment: You use vuex store not local storage in given snippet

Comment: Hello, is auth only return state.userLogin == true, if return true resume my function, if return false go to /login page.

Comment: Can you provide your browser log when you do this?